# How to grouping column header devexpress

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Anyone know how to create a view like this using gridview DEVEXPRESS?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Views and Levels](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3462) help article:

You can use one of the following View types to display data according to your needs:
 ...

- **Banded Grid View** - displays data in a tabular form similar to a Grid View, while organizing columns into bands.
- **Advanced Banded Grid View** - displays data similar to a Banded Grid View. However, columns can be arranged one under another and can have different heights.

Related help articles:
[Banded Grid View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3467)
[Customizing the Band Layout](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument727)